# Show that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ≡ 0\mod n$ for $n$ an odd prime number.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need help to prove the following question.

Show that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ≡ 0\mod n$ for $n$ an odd prime number.

I have thought about it, since $n$ is odd I can express it as $2k+1$.

I can also express $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ≡ 0\mod n$ as $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ≡ qn+0$.

I would appreciate any help to prove the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The prime part doesn't matter.  If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even and $\frac {n+1}2$ is an integer.

Comment: But how do you know that the entire expression is divisible by $n$? Oh, sorry, of course, because dividing by $2$ has not "affected" the value of $n$.

Comment: Because you get $n\cdot\text{integer}$.

Comment: @barakmanos:  because it is $n$ multiplied by an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed $n$ being odd one can write it as $n=2k+1$. And so we have

$${n(n+1)\over 2}=(2k+1)(k+1)=n(k+1)$$

And we have our result. We didn't need that $n$ is prime. The result is valid for any odd number.

Comment: Hi Marwalix, just to confirm my understanding does it mean that the final result is just expressing in the form of  (n(n+1))/2 ≡ qn+0 when q is k+1. Hence, this would prove that  (n(n+1))/2 ≡ 0 mod n ?

Comment: Yes you're right

Answer (score 0):

If we write
$$\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = qn,$$
then we are trying to show that for all odd prime $n,$ $q$ is an integer.

Working with this equation, we have
$$n(n + 1) = 2qn$$
$$n + 1 = 2q$$
$$q = \frac{n + 1}{2}.$$

But since $n$ is odd (given), then $q$ is an integer. We have thus finished the proof.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, the $n + 1$ is even.  So $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = n\frac{n+1}{2} = nk$ where $n+1 = 2k$ for some $k$ an integer (because $n + 1$ is even).

Likewise if $n$ is even then $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = (n+1)\frac{n}{2}= (n+1)k \equiv 0 \mod (n+1)$.